# addEventListener pointing to a function as an object's property, without firing the function on load

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a text-based, in-browser simple RPG for a friend. I want to generate menu elements from objects, and add eventListeners to them that activate the related function stored inside the object upon clicking. I have the code--

```js
var inventory = [
 {
  name: "first",
 },
 {
  name: "second",
  use: function(){
   alert ("placeholder function");
  }
 },
 {
  name: "third",
 },
];

function displayInventory(){
 for(i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML += '<div class="big_div" id="additional_div_' + inventory[i].name + '"> ' + inventory[i].name + ' div';
  if(inventory[i].hasOwnProperty("use")){
   document.getElementById("additional_div_" + inventory[i].name).innerHTML += '<div class="item_use" id="additional_div_use_' + inventory[i].name + '">click here to use item' 
   document.getElementById("additional_div_use_" + inventory[i].name).addEventListener("click", inventory[i].use()); // fires upon loading
   document.getElementById("additional_div_" + inventory[i].name).innerHTML += '</div>'
  }
  document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML += '</div>'
 }
}


document.onload = displayInventory();
```

```css
<style>
 .big_div{
  background-color:#ccc;
  margin:10px;
 }
 .item_use{
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>GAME</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="div_name"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this will fire the function intended for the use of the item upon loading, instead of upon clicking. I understand that this happens because the browser reads the function call when it reaches it in the code, but I couldn't come up with a workaround that also retains the generator-style loading.

I need the generator to work, because there will be a ton of items, maps, enemies etc., all loaded into the menu the same way.

I prefer to use vanilla JS for the whole thing.

Comment: You can use runnable stack snippets to get the code to run in the question itself.

Comment: I do want to load the entire menu upon loading the page, I just don't want the item's "use" function to do anything until the corresponding menu item is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain js (forEach etc) for that. You do not need to resort to innerHTML for this. Use `createElement` instead (also if you want to minimize dom modification consider using `new DocumentFragment` or `createDocumentFragment` instead, here I did not use it):

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/9uo8wuro/

```
var inventory = [
    {
        name: "first",
    },
    {
        name: "second",
        use: function(){
            alert   ("placeholder function");
        }
    },
    {
        name: "third",
    },
];

var container = document.getElementById("div_name");
inventory.forEach(function(d,i){
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.textContent = d.name && d.name || "placeholder";
   div.className = "item_use";
   div.id = "additional_div_use"+i;
   d.use && div.addEventListener("click",d.use,false);
   this.appendChild(div);
},container);
```

And here is an updated version based on what you want. If the object has children property, then  it will use that array to add elements ([*elementType*,*text*,*class*]), otherwise it will use the `name` property to add text content:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/9uo8wuro/2/

```
var inventory = [
    {
        name: "first",
    },
    {
        name: "second",
        use: function(){
            alert   ("placeholder function");
        },
        children:[["div","click here to use item","item_use"]]
    },
    {
        name: "third",
    },
];

var container = document.getElementById("div_name");
inventory.forEach(function(d,i){
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   !d.children && (div.textContent = d.name && d.name || "placeholder");
   div.id = "additional_div_use"+i;
   d.use && div.addEventListener("click",d.use,false);
   d.children && d.children.forEach(function(dd,ii){
       var el = document.createElement(dd[0]);
       el.textContent = dd[1] || "";
       el.className = dd[2] || "";
       this.appendChild(el);
   },div);
   this.appendChild(div);
},container);
```

Comment: Whoa this is pretty concise. All I need is to have the "clck here to use item" thing inside the second div and that part to be the only thing with the "item_use" class.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the answer based on what you want. Anytime, you provide a children key, which is an array of arrays having the element type as first, the text as second and the className as third index, it will populate the parent div.

Comment: Thanks! It will take some time to reverse engineer this and apply to all my menus, but at least I'll learn something in the process.

Comment: Sure, if something is not clear, let me know. Good luck with your project.